# Retrieve data from database inside bootstrap tab

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the same ad id(ad_id) in both tabs (section A & B). When I select section A it is working properly but when I select section B I could not get the data.

Code as follows:

```
<div><?php $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            $db=mysql_select_db("bil",$connect) ;

            $query=mysql_query("select ad_id from ad limit 5"); ?>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li ><a href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>Section A<?php while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ echo $r['ad_id'].'-';} ?></h3>

        </div>
        <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade active">
            <h3>Section B<?php while($r1=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ echo $r1['ad_id'].'-';} ?></h3>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: active class is mess remove it from all section b double check your markup

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc() returns the next row, and moves the internal pointer to the next row. When all rows have been returned, it returns null. So in your second while loop, you are trying to loop over null. YOu should also switch to mysqli rather than the deprecated mysql

Rewrite your code like this:

```
<?php 
$r=mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$r1=mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
 <h3>Section A<?php while($r){ echo $r['ad_id'].'-';} ?></h3>
</div>

<div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade active">
 <h3>Section B<?php while($r1){ echo $r1['ad_id'].'-';} ?></h3>
</div>
```